# How to convert GET parameter to another format in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

In my Rails app I have a simple form that filters all the user's `invoices` by date:

```
<%= form_tag invoices_path, :method => 'get' do %>

  <%= text_field_tag :date, params[:date] %>

  <%= submit_tag "Search" %>

<% end %>
```

When a user enters a date in his preferred date format, e.g. `27/07/2014`, I want this to be shown in the URL as `/invoices?date=2014-07-14` because this can be handled much more easily by the database and also looks better than `/invoices?date=25%2F07%2F2014`.

Is there any way to *convert* a GET parameter like this in Rails?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the date prettifying is to be done **on the client** side, since you want the pretty value to be shown in the query params already.

The `form_tag` may be supplied with `onsubmit` callback:

```
<%= form_tag invoices_path, 
             :method => 'get' 
             :onsubmit => 'return validate(this)' do %>
```

Here `validate()` would be a javascript validation method that would return `true` or `false`; you are free to prettify and overwrite the date value there.

Probably there is a more elegant way to accomplish that, but the aforementioned one worked well for me. Hope it helps.